# Ошибка при скачивании некоторых файлов(на примере NodeJS)

Tags: windows, windows-10

При скачивании NodeJS выдает такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать? Помогите, пожалуйста!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запустить системную службу «Установщик Windows» (Windows Installer), которую вы зачем-то выключили

Comment: Ну и вообще первая ссылка в гyгле https://remontka.pro/sluzhba-windows-installer-nedostupna/

Comment: Мне нечего из этого не помогло

Comment: А случаем у тебя не порносборка винды с нескучными обоями? Можно скрин свойств системы?

Comment: куда тебе скинуть?

Comment: Просто я не помню что за сборка, но скорее всего ты прав

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос - скинь скрин туда.

Comment: Скинул скрин...

Comment: Нечасто вижу, чтобы на ноутбуках была лицушная PRO-ха. И ни разу не видел, чтобы на немодифицированной винде были такие системные шрифты для гуя. Качай ванильную отсюда: https://software-download.microsoft.com/pr/Win10_1909_Russian_x64.iso?t=a8d4c854-5127-405a-81b5-639e44da3e03&e=1578829049&h=824a481efcc7dde8be65da789ab833f2 ставь, а потом будем смотреть, если и на этой не поедет. Да, если активировал через цифровую лицензию - то всё круто.

Comment: Можно как-то перебить её без потери данных на дисках?

Comment: Да, но раз ты задаёшь такой вопрос - сохрани важные файлы на другой физический диск\в облако. А потом переставляй.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103171/discussion-between-don-rumata-and-marron).